# ASP.NET MVC : Form values get cached after the first post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I might be doing something completely wrong here but for some reason the values of this form i have in one of my pages get cached after the first post. This is not a browser thing because even if i open a different browser the values posted are still cached.

My form is very simple:

```
<form action="/post/save" method="post">
    <label>Type here whatever you want, quick and without thinking</label>
    <%= Html.TextArea("Body", new { @class = "post", rows="3" })%>
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="big_button red" />
</form>
```

My controller action is even simpler:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Save(ArticleView form)
    {
        Article article = _ArticleViewMapper.Map(form);

        article.UpdatedBy = "guest";
        article.CreatedBy = "guest";
        article.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        article.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

        CMSFactory.CMS.ArticleRepository.Save(article);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

The form object has only an ID and a Body property. Right at the top of the method, this object has the body of the previous (actually the first) post request. is there any caching going on that i am not familiar with? thx

**EDIT:**

I found that the origin of the problem is the way i register my controllers. In my application_start I have the following code:

```
        // This only initialized the Castle IOC container
        DependencyRegistrat.Init();

        DependencyRegistrat.GetDefaultContainer().RegisterAll<IController>(typeof(HomeController).Assembly, ComponentLifecycle.Transient);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory(DependencyRegistrat.GetDefaultContainer()));
```

MyControllerFactory is as follows:

```
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        Check.IsNotNull(controllerType, "The given controller type was null, but must be provided");

        return (IController) _Container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller) 
    {
        var disposable = controller as IDisposable;

        if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();

        _Container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning a singleton controller instead of a new instance per request is a common mistake when writing a controller factory.  The recently released MVC 2 Preview 2 checks for this condition and displays an error describing the solution, so future developers shouldn't run into this same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the controller registration. I am using Castle's IOC container and for some reason,

this (which works):

```
_Container.AddComponentLifeStyle(typeof(K).FullName.ToLower(), typeof(K), (lifecycle);
```

is different that this (which doesnt work)

```
_Container.AddComponentLifeStyle<I, K>(lifecycle);
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that's not the `ModelState` keeping the post data cached? Because that's where the HtmlHelpers (`Html.TextArea()` in this case) get their values from.

Try adding `ModelState.Clear();` before redirecting in your `Save` action.

Or if you just want to clear that field, rather than the whole ModelState, then :
`ModelState["Body"].Value =  new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out what was magically caching, you answer finally gave the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding a new article or updating an existing one?

If you are updating an existing article you should be retrieving the existing article from the repository first.

If you are creating a new article you should be newing up an Article object.

Comment: forget about the data access code. its always a new article. the problem is at the very top of this method before i even start writing to the db. I found the origin of the problem but not the solution :( Check the Edit for more details